# Zoho Bookings SDK JS Server

Tags: javascript, sdk, server-side, zoho

Hi I'm trying to find documentation for Zoho Bookings but I only see the API v1, but is not suitable for my current proyect so I wanted to install the SDK to use it from the server and handle all the request from there, but I can't find any information on the internet I found two links that give a 404 ann nothing else\

Does anyone have an idea of where I can find documentation for the SDK and the SDK himself?

I tried to use this two links to get the information and the SDK but none of them really ```

`workhttps://www.zoho.com/bookings/developer/docs/javascript-sdk/v2/`

`https://www.zoho.com/bookings/developer/docs/javascript-sdk/v2/overview.html`